# Using find and xargs to list the timestamp of a file which has found from a containing string

Tags: linux, timestamp, xargs

I have to find a file from a given string inside and list this files timestamp only using find and xargs commands in linux command terminal

I've tried this code and it worked out but it gives error on ls command for long lines, need more smooth answer for this particular problem

```
find /home/stajyer -type f -exec grep -H 'ayberk' {} \; |xargs ls -l
```

Result:

```
ls: cannot access '/home/stajyer/myNameChangedFile/aFileInChangedFile4:ayberk': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'Binary': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'file': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'matches': No such file or directory
-rw------- 1 stajyer stajyer 9787 Haz 25 09:45 /home/stajyer/.bash_history
```

how can my code give less error corresponding to ls command?

Comment: It seems you just want output the filename from `grep`, why not using `grep -l` directly? Check the man page about it for details.

Answer (score 0):

From [man xargs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html):

> xargs reads
>    items from the standard input, delimited by blanks (which can be
>    protected with double or single quotes or a backslash) or newlines,

To disable that you can go with a zero delimetered stream and use `-0` or `--null` option with `xargs` and `-print0` with `find`. It would look like this:

```
find /home/stajyer -type f -exec grep -qH 'ayberk' {} \; -print0 | xargs -0 ls -l
```

Tested on [repl](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/SameWellgroomedRecovery).

Comment: In your new code it gives an output of ls: cannot access '/home/stajyer/myNameChangedFile/aFileInChangedFile4:ayberk'$'\n''/home/stajyer/myNameChangedFile/aFileInChangedFile4': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'Binary file /home/stajyer/.bash_history matches'$'\n''/home/stajyer/.bash_history': No such file or directory
which is eliminating  the last timestamp

Comment: I changed yours to find /home/stajyer -type f -exec grep -H 'ayberk' {} \; -print0 | xargs ls -l Now it gives : the correct time but with too many errors